# SSIS script component *bug* – Column data type DT_DBDATE is not supported by the PipelineBuffer class

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Does anyone know exactly why these types of issues happen using a script component that can be “fixed” by deleting and re add the same code to make fix this type of issue?  Why would metadata change when you delete and re add code? what happens inside the engine when this happens? What kind of issue could it ever fix to delete and re add a script component, copy the same code and rewire it?

I can reproduce at will with the following steps:

1. Took a working package with a script component and two output buffers. The script component has additional input columns and output columns setup for the second output buffer that are not being populated yet by the source query (OLE DB source SQL command) yet.  Only one column is being populated in the second output buffer from the source query .
2. Copied in a new source query with additional columns for the second output buffer.
3. Run the package. Get the error message Column data type DT_DBDATE is not supported by the PipelineBuffer class.
4. Comment out the two lines for the second output buffer, run the package, the package runs successfully:

   RedactedOutputBuffer.AddRow();

   RedactedOutputBuffer. RedactedColumnName = Row. RedactedColumnName;
5. Uncomment the ***same*** two lines. The package still works. **So the package is now exactly the same as when it did not work.**

Comment: If you cast whatever date columns are coming out of your SQL query as datetime data types, does it still fail to run?

Comment: Here's a hint that has served me well for many years - it's almost _never_ a bug in the {compiler, tool, operating system}.

Comment: Are you on 2005? `there is no way to set it in SQL 2005. The good news is that in SQL 2008 it does work. In addition, there are GetTime/SetTime methods that work with DT_DBTIME as well. Wednesday, September 05, 2007 7:15 AM`

Comment: I just had the same problem. The problem was that in my T-SQL query field had type `int` instead of `DATE` and *SSIS Script Component* `Row.Field` was of type `DateTime`. Try revalidating metadata in SSIS package. Maybe this will help... even after one year :)

Comment: Here's a hint that has served me well for many years - it's almost _always_ a bug in the Microsoft software, which has too many bugs to count.  You used to be able to share the workarounds at "Microsoft Connect", but since everyone could see how many years (and decades) they left their bugs unfixed, they eventually became embarrassed and deleted "Microsoft Connect".

Answer (score -2):

Well, no, it's not really a bug, it's more like SSIS doesn't try to be clever and fit square pegs in round holes.

I mean the error message is pretty clear, innit? The PipelineBuffer class doesn't have any methods to handle data types of DT_DBDATE. So it throws you a [UnsupportedBufferDataTypeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.unsupportedbufferdatatypeexception.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when assigning a value to a buffer column
>   that contains the incorrect data type.

Anyway, since you didn't print your full error message stack, it's hard to say exactly but my guess is it tried to call SetDateTime (or GetDateTime ) on your busted column. So when you set your source query, it sets the pipeline buffer's data type as DT_DBDATE, but when you comment it out, let it run, then uncomment it out, it has converted the pipeline buffer's data type to DT_DBTIMESTAMP, which is compatible with SetDateTime or whatever method is being called from the PipelineBuffer class which is throwing your error.

Anyway, [this MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/320c9564-467e-4a55-b92f-6a40d4a84e03/there-is-no-pipelinebufferset-method-for?forum=sqlintegrationservices) should give you a little more flavor on what you're seeing, but the bottom line is make sure that the field coming out of your source query is correctly identified as the field type you want it to be in your destination. If that's a SQL Server datetime field, you either need to cast it as datetime in your source query or use a Data Conversion component to explicitly cast it for your script component.

Comment: the line of code that I am commenting out then afterwards uncommenting, (the uncommenting which gets rid of the error message), refers to a column of type DT_STR.

Comment: I had thought that i made clear that the column was DT_STR, but unfortunately I had not.

Comment: its a little frustrating to me that i did not communicate my thoughts my clearly. As a result there has been a lot of input, but its based on the wrong information, and some of the answers sound as if I had asked a stupid question "I mean the error message is pretty clear, innit?". I posted even though i can work around this type of issue because i strongly believe SSIS error messages can be very unclear.

Comment: Does anyone on this forum believe that sometimes you have to delete and re add the same script component to fix an error?? This is well known in my shop and i posted to try to get to the bottom of why this  happens.

Comment: per Kyle's suggestion i cast the two columns that are coming in as DT_DBDATE (even though they are being successfully populated by the original package without error) as both varchar and datetime, and still get the error. I think this is a blind alley though. i do notice that casting does not change the metadata in the output column of the OLEDB Source nor the input column to the script component - its still DBDATE. I still think this is a *red herring* because i have fixed similar problems this week with the same error message and type of DT_STR.

Comment: Your error is entirely based on metadata changes you are introducing by adding your query which the PipelineBuffer instance of your script component is unable to handle. If you add steps to your package to ensure a consistent set of metadata for your script component regardless of what data types are coming out of your source query, your issue will go away.

Comment: I should be clear: I wasn't saying your question is stupid, I was saying that the error message you're seeing is a known one due to known issues, and that MSDN forum I posted explains the workaround within a script component to data types which are not able to be parsed using standard Set* and Get* methods.

Comment: @gnackerson Yes, casting won't change the metadata, you have to either set the output and input columns explicitly or remove them and then allow SSIS to recreate them using the new metadata.

Comment: Kyle thanks for  your thoughtful responses. I can see that casting does not work with an existing source query . So, thinking that SSIS was saving prior metadata,  i deleted and re added the OLE DB Source DFT using the same source query. Now i get column type DT_STR not supported by the PipeLineBuffer class!  there is no unicode/non unicode stuff going on here, and i see no reason why a script component would choke on DT_STR which is used everywhere. With respect , I still think there is something buggy going on here!

Comment: "The PipelineBuffer class doesn't have any methods to handle data types of DT_DBDATE."... Ok, fair enough, but am i now supposed to believe this statement is true of "workhorse type" like DT_STR?? fishy error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72353/discussion-between-gnackenson-and-kyle-hale).

Comment: @gnackenson - yes - to answer your previous comment above about removing and adding a component - there have been numerous times when I've had something just stop working with this kind of error.  Then, I simply remove it and add the same component back - doing a copy/paste with the code and it works fine.  In this case today, I had a very similar error - only with a DT_I4 and a DT_I8 data type as the source of the issue.  I did the copy/paste - now works fine.  I go by the adage - SSIS is a piece of Junk, but it is the best piece of junk out there (for data transfer and integration).